# Iterate through all rows Smartsheet API Python

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am trying to iterate through all the rows in a sheet, but it seems that simply using .rows is limited to returning 100 items.

```
for temp_row in inventory.rows:
    x += 1
print x #X will always return <= 100
```

No matter how many items I have in there.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Just to clarify, I am trying to do something to every row, not count them, that is just an example of how i noticed it is only grabbing 100 rows.

Comment: have you tried `len(inventory.rows)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, get_sheet will return a page with 100 rows. Include the flag: `includeAll=true` to return all rows.

See the [documentation on paging](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#paging) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The `include_all` parameters is not part of `get_sheet()`.

The parameter in the <kbd>Python SDK 2.0</kbd> is `page_size`

and defaults to `100`.

```
my_sheet = smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id, page_size=5000)
```

where `sheet_id` is your sheet's ID.

If you already have the sheet object, you could use

```
my_sheet.total_row_count
```

to get the number of rows and use that instead of `5000`.

Comment: yes the old docs has ```pageSize=``` but you are right ```page_size=``` is the one that work now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like perhaps the SDK is utilizing *paging* when executing the **Get Sheet** operation -- i.e., it's only returning the first page of results in the response, which defaults to 100 rows. As described in the [API docs](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet), page size defaults to 100 rows in the **Get Sheet** response, unless specified otherwise by the request. (In the docs, see the description for the **pageSize** and **page** parameters.)

I'd suggest that you review the SDK for the ability to specify **pageSize** and/or **page** when calling the **Get Sheet** operation.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that when making the request to the Smartsheet API directly rather than via the Python SDK the default response is to include all rows of the sheet without needing to include `page` or `pageSize` parameters.